# dynamic dropdown get in zf2?

Tags: zend-framework2

I want to put a dropdown in my project which is made in zf2... I wasted all day but I only got a static dropdown, not dynamic. Can anyone help me with this problem??

UserForm.php

```
$this->add(array(
            'name' => 'group_name',
            'type' => 'select',  
            'attributes' => array(
                'id'=>'group_name',
                'class'=>'large',
                'options' => array('1=>php','2'=>'java'),
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => '',
            ),
        ));
```

Thanks in advance for your valuabe answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'group_name',
    'type' => 'select',  
    'attributes' => array(
        'id'=>'group_name',
        'class'=>'large',
    ),
    'options' => array(
        'label' => '',
        'value_options' => array(
            '1' => 'php', 
            '2' => 'java'
        ),
    ),
));
```

Comment: no it's display only static dropdown but i want dynamic which get value from database and display it.

Comment: What have you tried? I don't see any DB related code in your question and no variable `$options`.

Comment: hey bram if you have any suggestion for get  dynamic dropdown from first step to last step so pls help me.. i am new in zf2..

Comment: Well, it's not more complex than retrieving the values you want from the database (using PDO, MysqlI, ZendDB, Doctrine 2 or whatever you are using) and then converting the results to the data structure that the Select list wants. That is a simple array with key/value pair.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did:

In my constructor for my form

```
    $this->add(array(
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
        'name' => 'color',
        'options' => array(
            'empty_option' => 'Select a Color',
            'value_options' => self::getColors(),
            'label' => 'Color',
        ),
    ));
```

In the form class yet, i created this method:

```
public static function getColors() {
    // access database here
    //example return
    return array(
        'blue' => 'Blue',
        'red'  => 'Red',
    );
}
```

In my view script:

```
    <div class="form_element">
        <?php $element = $form->get('color'); ?>
        <label>
            <?php echo $element->getOption('label'); ?>
        </label>
        <?php echo $this->formSelect($element); ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about it from a abstract level.

- You have one Form
- The Form needs Data from the outside

So ultimately your Form has a `Dependency`. Since we've learned from the [official docs](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/quickstart.di.html), there's two types of `Dependency-Injection` aka `DI`. Setter-Injection and Constructor-Injection. Personally(!) i use one or the other in those cases:

**Constructor-Injection** if the dependency is an absolute requirement for the functionality to work

**Setter-Injection** if the dependencies are more or less optional to extend already working stuff

In the case of your Form, it is a required dependency (because without it there is no populated Select-Element) hence i'll be giving you an example for Constructor-Injection.

Some action of your controller:

```
$sl   = $this->getServiceLocator();
$dbA  = $sl->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
$form = new SomeForm($dbA);
```

That's all for the form. The population now happens inside your Form. This is only an example and may need some fine-tuning, but you'll get the idea:

```
class SomeForm extends \Zend\Form
{
    public function __construct(\Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter $dbA)
    {
        parent::__construct('my-form-name');

        // Create all the form elements and stuff

        // Get Population data
        $popData = array();
        $result = $dbA->query('SELECT id, title FROM Categories', $dbA::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE)->toArray();
        foreach ($result as $cat) {
            $popData[$cat['id'] = $cat['title'];
        }

        $selectElement = $this->getElement('select-element-name');
        $selectElement->setValueOptions($popData);
    }   
}
```

**Important**: I HAVE NO CLUE ABOUT `Zend\Db` the above code is only for how i think it would work going by [the docs](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.db.sql.html)! This is the part that would need some optimization probably. But all in all you'll get the idea of how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you can do something like below;

On my first example assuming that you have a Group Table. Then we're going to fetchAll the data in group table;
We need the id and name to be display in select options;

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $groupTable = new GroupTable();
    $groupList = $groupTable->fetchAll();

    $groups = array();
    foreach ($groupList as $list) {
        $groups[$list->getId()] = $list->getName();
    }    

    $form = new UserForm();
    $form->get('group_name')->setAttributes(array(
        'options' => $groups,   
    )); 
}
```

OR

in this example the grouplist is hardcoded;

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $groupList = array('1' => 'PHP', '2' => 'JAVA', '3' => 'C#');

    $groups = array();
    foreach ($groupList as $id => $list) {
        $groups[$id] = $list;
    }    

    $form = new UserForm();
    $form->get('group_name')->setAttributes(array(
        'options' => $groups,   
    )); 
}
```

Then in your view script;

```
<?php 
    $form = $this->form;
    echo $this->formRow($form->get('group_name')); 
?>
```

Or you can right a controller helper, you may check this link http://www.resourcemode.com/me/?p=327

Answer (score 0):

Just came across the same problem and had to take a look into zf2 source.
Here's a more OOP solution:

Inside the form constructor:

```
        $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'customer',
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
        'attributes' => array(
            'options' => array(
                0 => 'Kunde',
            )
        ),
        'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Kunde'
    )));
```

inside the controller:

```
    $view->form = new SearchForm();
    $customers = $view->form->get('customer')->getValueOptions();
    $customers[] = 'Kunde1';
    $customers[] = 'Kunde2';
    $customers[] = 'Kunde3';
    $customers[] = 'Kunde4';
    $view->form->get('customer')->setValueOptions($customers);
```